# Displaying two divs in one row using seperate foreach

Tags: c#, css, foreach, styles, display

I would like separate my data populated in the view into different columns using bootstrap. What's happening now, all results in second foreach is displaying under all results in the first foreach. I would like to...

In the first foreach display all results in column 1.

And the second foreach display all results in column 2..

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        @foreach (var winner in Model.AwardWinners.Where(x => x.Type == 1))
        {
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 d-block">
                <div class="colourbar"></div>
                <div class="awardWinnersBox">
                    <div class="top-info">

                        <div class="soloAuthorPhoto">
                            <img src="" alt="" onerror="this.src = '/images/noProfilePhoto.png'" />
                        </div>

                        <div class="authordetails">
                            <div class="soloAuthorHeading"></div>
                            <div class="soloAuthorName"></div>
                        </div>


                        <div class="verticalDivide"></div>
                        <div class="award">
                            <img src="/images/AwardWinners/thought-leader-logo.png" alt="" class="typeImage" />
                            <div class="awardName">
                                @winner.AwardName
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="title"><a href="">test</a></div>
                    <div class="eventTimeDetails">@(winner.Contact ?? "")</div>
                    <span class="bottomLine"></span>
                    <div class="firmMask">
                        <img src="" onerror="this.src='/images/lex-linkedin.png'" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        }

        @foreach (var winner in Model.AwardWinners.Where(x => x.Type == 2))
        {
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                <div class="colourbar"></div>
                <div class="awardWinnersBox">
                    <div class="top-info">

                        <div class="soloAuthorPhoto">
                            <img src="" alt="" onerror="this.src = '/images/noProfilePhoto.png'" />
                        </div>

                        <div class="authordetails">
                            <div class="soloAuthorHeading"></div>
                            <div class="soloAuthorName"></div>
                        </div>


                        <div class="verticalDivide"></div>
                        <div class="award">
                            <img src="/images/AwardWinners/Legal-influencer-logo.png" alt="" />
                            <div class="awardName">
                                @winner.AwardName 
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="title"><a href="">test</a></div>
                    <div class="eventTimeDetails">@(winner.Contact ?? "")</div>
                    <span class="bottomLine"></span>
                    <div class="firmMask">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add columns first, then the content:

```
<div class="container">
  <!--Column 1-->
  <div class="col-6">
    <!-- For each 1 -->
  </div>

  <!--Column 2-->
  <div class="col-6">
    <!-- For each 2 -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Keep in mind that you will have to apply the layout to the 2 cols and the content blocks should occupy 100% of the columns.